# Q:How can i Combine a fluid simulation with an ocean plane?

Tags: workflow, fluid-simulation, ocean-simulation

I want to create a boat that floats across an ocean for an animation something like this in Moana: https://gyazo.com/b6bae882baad57b4da22549bb50ade43
but I just can't figure out how to combine the ocean layer with the fluid domain.
I have been searching for days I found a description of what I'm looking for but he didn't explain how one might do it here's the link to the thread that describes it better than I can: [Is the ocean modifier better than the fluid simulation for making an ocean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14545/is-the-ocean-modifier-better-than-the-fluid-simulation-for-making-an-ocean)
I would love to hear from someone who knows how the big studios do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete tutorial on how to combine ocean modifier and fluid sim to generate exactly what you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVwfEHtLiyI

And here is a simpler version just with the Ocean Modifier (for zoomed out shots for example): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smArCTzxGpE

Both techniques can be combined but tend to be resource-intensive when rendering. I would move between two scenes (close and wide) to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution that's in my mind but I've never tried.

Use a harmonic force field on the ocean plane with a strength 30 to 50. Now the fluid simulation will take the shape of the ocean plane.